# Set request header of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, hyperlink

Is there any way to have a link hold a request header? I am trying to open a specific page from an application outside of the web server, but the page requires authentication. So far, everyone seems to say it is impossible.

Comment: You _can_ try to do it with some backend server code I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperlinks can not hold header information.

You may be able to set headers for an AJAX request, assuming the security conditions are met (same domain or CORS).

Take a look at [the jQuery AJAX reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to learn about sending an ajax request with headers

Comment: Thanks, ajax is probably going to be the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the other site is using basic http authentification you can set the username and password in the url, but that is not secure.

```
http://user:password@yoursite.com/
```